# t-SQL compound statement causes the deadlock, any idea why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I'm in the process of learning a more complex SQL Server 2008 techniques so I apologize in advance if I ask a too obvious question.

I have the following table created as such:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
(
   [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
   [oid] INT, 
   [idtm] DATETIME2, 
   [odtm] DATETIME2, 
   [type] TINYINT, 
   [state] TINYINT, 
   [huid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
   [cnm] NVARCHAR(256), 
   [cmdl] NVARCHAR(256), 
   [batt] TINYINT, 
   [dvtp0] SMALLINT, 
   [dvtp1] SMALLINT
);

CREATE INDEX idx_idt 
          ON [dbo].[t_Log_2]([idtm]);

CREATE INDEX idx_odt 
          ON [dbo].[t_Log_2]([odtm]);

CREATE INDEX idx_huid 
          ON [dbo].[t_Log_2]([huid]);

CREATE INDEX idx_cnm 
          ON [dbo].[t_Log_2]([cnm]);
```

And then the following query can be run from **several simultaneous threads** from an ASP.NET web application. Note that this whole query needs to run **atomically**:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
      WHERE [idtm]<'2011-03-12 08:41:57';

WITH ctx AS(
     SELECT MIN([idtm]) AS mdIn, 
            MAX([odtm]) AS mdOut 
           FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
          WHERE [type] = 0 
            AND [state] = 0 
            AND [huid] = N'18ef4d56-6ef3-906a-a711-88d1bd6ab2d4' 
            AND [odtm] >= '2013-03-11 06:33:32' 
            AND [idtm] <= '2013-03-11 06:43:12' 
           ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
([oid],[idtm],[odtm],[type],[state],[huid],
 [cnm],[cmdl],[batt],[dvtp0],[dvtp1]) 
SELECT 
    2, 
    CASE WHEN mdIn IS NOT NULL 
          AND mdIn < '2013-03-11 06:33:32' 
         THEN mdIn 
         ELSE '2013-03-11 06:33:32' 
         END,
    CASE WHEN mdOut IS NOT NULL 
          AND mdOut > '2013-03-11 06:43:12' 
         THEN mdOut 
         ELSE '2013-03-11 06:43:12' 
         END,
    0,
    0,
    N'18ef4d56-6ef3-906a-a711-88d1bd6ab2d4',
    null,
    null,
    0,
    1,
    null 
FROM ctx 

SELECT ROWCOUNT_BIG()

DELETE FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
      WHERE [type] = 0 
        AND [state] = 0 
        AND [huid] = N'18ef4d56-6ef3-906a-a711-88d1bd6ab2d4' 
        AND [odtm] >= '2013-03-11 06:33:32' 
        AND [idtm] <= '2013-03-11 06:43:12' 
        AND [id] <> SCOPE_IDENTITY()

DELETE FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
      WHERE [type] = 0 
        AND [huid] = N'18ef4d56-6ef3-906a-a711-88d1bd6ab2d4' 
        AND [idtm] >= (SELECT [idtm] FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
                                    WHERE [id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()) 
        AND [odtm] <= (SELECT [odtm] FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
                                    WHERE [id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()) 
        AND [id] <> SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

;WITH ctx1 AS( 
     SELECT [idtm] AS dI 
       FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
      WHERE [id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
             )
UPDATE [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
        SET [odtm] = ctx1.dI 
       FROM ctx1 
      WHERE [id] <> SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
        AND [type] = 0 
        AND [huid] = N'18ef4d56-6ef3-906a-a711-88d1bd6ab2d4' 
        AND [idtm] < ctx1.dI 
        AND [odtm] > ctx1.dI 

;WITH ctx2 AS(
     SELECT [odtm] AS dO 
       FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
      WHERE [id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
             ) 
UPDATE [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
        SET [idtm] = ctx2.dO 
       FROM ctx2 
      WHERE [id] <> SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
        AND [type] = 0 
        AND [huid] = N'18ef4d56-6ef3-906a-a711-88d1bd6ab2d4' 
        AND [idtm] < ctx2.dO 
        AND [odtm] > ctx2.dO 

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

Note that the query above was copied 1-to-1 from the C# code that dynamically composes it. In reality its parameters are not hard-coded as is shown above.

This query works in most times but once in a while I get the following error in the log:

> Transaction (Process ID 80) was deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

Any idea what shall I do to prevent this deadlock?

Comment: Use UPDLOCK hints on your selects.

Comment: Capture and attach the deadlock Graph (the XML, not the picture of it!) see [Save Deadlock Graphs (SQL Server Profiler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx)

Comment: @Arvo: Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: I have encountered deadlock on situations, where (inside transaction) I initially select some values from table and then update same table. Using UPDLOCK hint in first select (select ... from ... with(updlock)) places IX type locks onto affected records already while selecting and other transactions will wait until this one is completed. For our troubles UPDLOCK hints solved the problem.

Comment: Also, free advice, save `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` into a variable for maintainability, rather than using it directly everywhere.

Comment: Note, that `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` might cause the tran to rollback on the first error but the batch to continue without transaction...

Comment: @usr has a good point. You really need `BEGIN TRY`/`END TRY` and rollback in the `CATCH` block.

Comment: @Ben transaction abortion is really awfully implemented in SQL Server. I wish there was an XACT_ABORT_BATCH option that would kill the batch in case of any unhandled error.

Comment: You were saying that the C# code dynamically generates your statements; can you use SqlTransaction.IsolationLevel to tweak your isolation levels?

Comment: @usr, that is what 'BEGIN TRY' is....

Comment: Sure it is possible to achieve this but you don't want to wrap basically *every* batch with this. Also does not work across batches which is nasty with long DDL scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to hold more locks or fewer.

The easiest answer is to go either `NOLOCK` (best performance) or `TABLOCKX` (consistency without having to think).

If you cannot use `with (nolock)` because of consistency requirements, you can add `with (tablockx)`.
This will effectively mean that only one thread can execute like statements at a time - there will be no concurrency.

The alternative is to analyse your requirements in a lot more detail, which cannot be done without an understanding why you are updating the table, what the data is for etc.

For example, does this statement really need to be in the transaction?  It smells like housekeeping:

```
  DELETE FROM [dbo].[t_Log_2] 
  WHERE [idtm]<'2011-03-12 08:41:57';
```

If you take that out of the transaction, and put it in a separate batch, you may find the problems go away.

Comment: with nolock rarely is the answer. Just use READ COMMITTED which will not hold locks, just take and release them. Will not contribute to deadlocking in a major way.